# c sharp mysql underscore, space table name error

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm trying to do a simple `SELECT` statement from a MySQL Database.
My table names contains `underscores (_)` and they could contain `spaces ( )` as well. I put the table name in backticks but I get SQL Syntax error.

Example of one of my query:

```
"SELECT * From '" + ID + "_" + objectName + "' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1"
```

If I do not use the backticks and the object name does not have any space in it, the query works.

Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: Do you get any error? Or does it just not work? What happens if you step through the code?

Comment: In mssql you would use brackets to handle tables with spaces. Like [my table].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not "*put the table name in backticks*", but rather in single quotes.  Use instead:

```
"SELECT * From `" + ID + "_" + objectName + "` ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1"
```

Beware: having variable table names of this sort generally indicates that one's schema violates the [Principle of Orthogonal Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_Orthogonal_Design), which can lead to a whole world of pain.  You may wish to consider combining all such records into a single table, with a column whose value indicates whatever differentiation exists between the existing tables.

Comment: Yes you right, such a stupid mistake:P Thank you. Now I just need to find a way to speed up the "get last row". Thanks!

Comment: @Daniel: Do you have an index on the `date` column?

Comment: No, I do not, I use the timeStamp as a unique key as well. It is just a collection of readings.

Comment: I could add an ID if that can speed up the process

Comment: @Daniel: You don't have an index on the `date` column, but the `timeStamp` (which is a different column?) is a `UNIQUE KEY`?  Can you not either sort by `timeStamp` instead of `date`, or else add an index over `date`?

Comment: Might be messy, but I could create one more Table for each object where I store just the last point, so when I query the data I always have just one entry in those tables. Is that a stupid idea?:P

Comment: date values are my timeStamps, sorry bad phrasing